# iphone app rejected but with not notification email

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I've recently had my app rejected, but they have not sent over the "explanation" email yet. has anyone experienced a rejection without a tandem explanation or reasoning from app review?

Comment: a) Check your spam box. b) Ask them.

Comment: How long has it been since your app was rejected?  Maybe it will take a little while for the email to be sent out...

Comment: just out of curiosity, why was your app rejected???

Comment: well i didnt even get an explanation.

Comment: it got rejected about 28 hours ago. but i hear the explanation email comes right away.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

When your app is rejected without a letter, it usually means it crashed. Check it out again and resubmit.

Comment: ok i will try that. how are you so sure? its been about two days since my itunes connect status has gone to "rejected".

Comment: When they reject right away without comment it's probably one of two things. It crashed when the reviewer launched it (non-specific error or compatibility, so no letter), or the App uses private APIs.

Comment: is there a channel for us to send them question why do they reject our apps?

Answer (score 1):

Could be the app not being compatible with OS 3.0.

Check this: [techradar.com - New iPhone Apps Must Be 3.0 Compatible](http://www.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/new-iphone-apps-must-by-3-0-compatible-597287)

Answer (score 0):

same thing happened to me, my app was rejected sometime last night, but I got no notification. It would suck if it was the 3.0 compatible issue because my app was submitted almost a week before that email came out.

Comment: thanks man. yeah, i got a private api non-compliance notification eventually. as it turns out, they usually send email notifications to your "support" email address you list on the upload area.

Answer (score 0):

Relax, we've got an app rejected in March, now it's July and we never got any explanation: sometimes they just don't send anything